# Laravel (Main Website) + Node (Scraper) + DB

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, laravel-4

I am creating a website using the Laravel framework that requires the utilization of some data.  This data is being collected by a scraper implemented with Node.js. My approach is to collect the data and store it on a database (MongoDB) and read it with Laravel.

I came across [this solution](http://www.volkomenjuist.nl/blog/2013/10/20/laravel-4-and-nodejsredis-pubsub-realtime-notifications/), should I work with it?

Is there another way to push data from Node.js into MongoDB and then read the same MongoDB in Laravel?

Comment: Have you tried using Node to push the data to Mongo, then Laravel to read it out?  Or are you saying you want to know how to do that?  Just trying to understand the question, since the link provided doesn't talk about Mongo

Comment: I am asking, should I even do it? If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Node.js app should save data into your MongoDB database, and your Laravel app should read that data only when needed - your solution is clearly not the way to go.

There is a library that allows using a MongoDB just like a standard database using the same Eloquent methods : [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb), you should definitely check it out and use it (or find an equivalent).

Comment: I am in the process of implementing laravel-mongodb per your suggestion. I will let you know how things turn out.

Comment: Thanks André, laravel-mongodb appears to be running as I intended.